# BSOD after update. Unbootable

Tags: windows-7, bsod

After a windows update I was gifted with a black screen of death. That one with the black screen and only a movable cursor before login.

No task manager, no safe mode, no startup recovery, no restore point, no nothing

Attempted the following commands (Shift+F10) at windows DVD:

```
- Chkdsk D:\ /r /x
No errors
- Sfc /scannow /offbootdir=d:\ offwindir=d:\windows
Windows resource protection could not perform the requested operation
```

The volume is D, not C. No typo in there.

Now I'm trying to remove the updates

```
Wmic qfe get hotfixid
No instances available
Dism /image:d:\ /Get-Package
Error 3: d:\windows does not look like a valid directory... Ensure /Windir option is valid...
```

I've tried uppercase, lowercase, c:, d: everything

Using notepad I found a WindowsUpdate log, and 
Inside of it, found the name of an update

```
Dism /Remove-Package /packagename:Package_for_KB...etcetcetcetera...
Error 87: remove-package option is unknown
```

**Edit.:**

Much probably those DISM commands are not working because the DISM is from system32.
I read (confusing) that there are other more complete versions of DISM (that came when I had the opportunity to install the readiness package)

Is it bull or real ? And if so, where

**Edit 2:**
Yep. It's bull
There's no such a thing as offline DISM for windows 7

Is there another way of uninstalling these updates ?

**Edit 3:**

Doesn't feel good to be adding this, since every helper here is voluntary, but I must: 
Kind on a hurry... It's a central computer to the office.

If this gets resolved, might be a big experience for both technicians and me. That is my main purpose, second, of course, to avoid reinstalling windows and every program

**Edit 4:**
I gave up. Ran out of time. Installed windows over

Comment: Restore from a backup, and then immediately block updates until you can get Win-7 working on a spare machine with the updates. Recent MS updates for all OS's other than their latest (e.g. Win-10) have caused similar failures. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-update/windows-7-updateproblems-read-this-first/28147a5f-b0b0-480b-bed9-834a2da7a375

Comment: I have not done backups of any kind, I'm afraid. I can acces any file, though. All I need is to make THIS system work again. No formatting or installing over

Comment: Impossible. The user of this computer is not advanced, nor has the time to learn. Plus, there are many softwares that would require too much patching (if comes to that point) to work, like Autocad and others

Comment: Then what you should do is plug the hard drive into a different computer, backup the necessary files, and then perform a clean installation of Windows 7.

Comment: Did you try save mode ? (Press repeatedly `F8` key after BIOS beeped)

Comment: Safe mode attempted. Including safemode minimal and safemode low resolution. All of them the same problem: black screen, cursor only.

Comment: I could simply install windows and forget this problem ever existed. But no. This must be resolved. It would happen all over since I will let the system update again. Plus, the pain to customize the system and install all the softwares would be tenfold of the one it takes to reinstall windows. I did it recently, twice, and won't do again.